# An internal error occurred when attempting to deliver data in AWS Firehose data stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am implement AWS kinesis-Firehose data stream and facing issue in data delivery from s3 to redshift. can you please help me and let me know what is missing?

> An internal error occurred when attempting to deliver data. Delivery
>   will be retried; if the error persists, it will be reported to AWS for
>   resolution.   InternalError   2

Answer (score 0):

It happened for me, and the problem was an error of inconsistency of the input record format the DB table.
Try to check [AWS Docs of COPY command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) to make sure the COPY command parameters are defined properly.